# Does anyone know of a webservice for looking up definitions of words that would be able to return results in JSON?

Tags: json, dictionary, web-services, lookup

I found http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php but nothing like this for definitions/dictionary.

Ideally I'd grab a dictionary file and build my own API for this, but this is for a demo and we need something short-term that can be called from within a javascript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wiktionary.org provides an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) for example:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Television&format=json
```

gives back

```
    {
       "query": {"searchinfo": {"totalhits": 208862},
       "search": [{ 
           "ns": 0, 
           "title": "Television", 
           "snippet": "<span class='searchmatch'>Television<\/span> (TV) is a widely used telecommunication  medium  for transmitting and receiving moving images , either monochromatic  (\"black  <b>...<\/b> ",
           "size": 28228, 
           "wordcount": 3566, 
           "timestamp": "2009-10-02T15:09:56Z"},
...
       ]},
       "query-continue": {"search": {"sroffset":10}}
    }
```

Comment: The Wiktionary API is just the MediaWiki API and it doesn't return definitions, it returns pages or sections of raw wiki markup or the same parsed into HTML. Either way you will have to then parse these results to extract the definitions, and there are multiple pitfalls in doing so. There do seem to be a good few projects accessing Wiktionary data though so despite the hurdles it is possible if you're determined and you're a good programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

- [bighugelabs API](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php)      - Json fromat
- [aonaware services](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx)    - XML format

Comment: If you read my question, I already know of big huge labs, and the point is to find an alternative that does dictionary lookups that can be called from JS.  SOAP based webservices aren't very javascript friendly, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any web service other than Aonaware for XML format as this service is currently not available?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would fit your needs, but answers.com has [webmaster tools](http://wiki.answers.com/about/Webmaster-tools.html) that offer various services, including dictionary lookup. Don't know if any can be called from javascript.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be much use for what I am trying to do, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At short notice you could set up a reverse-proxy on your server that lets you AJAX your favorite dictionary website and then 'scrape' the definitions from the document that is returned.  It's obviously not a long term solution but for a one time thing, you probably won't get into trouble.

Comment: Well, this may be my only option at this point - I'm surprised there isn't something more readily available, so maybe I'll build something and then others can use it too - as it seems like an incredibly common need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a web service and have several dictionaries:

http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx

P.S.  I did not notice the JSON part of your question.

Comment: Is there any web service other than Aonaware for XML format as this service is currently not available?

Comment: I do not know of another service but I just checked and the one one I mentioned is online and working.

Comment: yeah it started working a say later I wrote this comment. The worst part was when I was giving a demo to my teacher, the server went down.